# Vector changing the size of class

Tags: c++, pointers, sizeof

**EDIT:**
Though badly formatted this Question had a nice catch.So, I am editing this to retain this in a better format for future visitors who stumble across this question.

---

In the code sample below can someone please explain Why is the size of class different than expected after `memcpy`? What is the reason?

**[Here](http://www.ideone.com/u4SWY)** is the online demo on Ideone.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstring>

using namespace std;

class A
{
    public:
        int a;
        virtual void f1() { cout <<"inside a::f1\n"; }
        A() { a = 1; }
};

class B
{
    public:
        int b;
        virtual void f2() { cout <<"inside b::f2\n"; }
        virtual void f5() { cout <<"inside b::f5\n"; }
        B() { b = 2; }
};

class C : public A, public B
{
    public:
        int c;
        void f1() { cout <<"inside c::f1\n"; }
        void f2() { cout <<"inside c::f2\n"; }

        virtual void f3() { cout <<"inside c::f3\n"; }
        virtual void f4() { cout <<"inside c::f4\n"; }
        C() { c = 3; }
};


int fun()
{
    int a = 1;
    return a * 2;
}

int main()
{
    C c;
    C c2;
    int (*g)() = &fun;

    void (A::*g1)() = &A::f1;
    void (C::*g2)();

    g2 = &C::f1;
    (c.*g2)();

    printf("%p\n",g2);
    cout << sizeof(g2) << endl;

    g2 = &C::f2;
    (c.*g2)();

    printf("%p\n", g2);

    // Why is the output 1 here in g++ or visual C++?
    cout << g2;
    // Why is the sizeof returning 8? Please explain.
    cout << sizeof(g2) << endl;

    g2 = &C::f1;
    std::vector<unsigned char> a_vec(sizeof(g2));

    memcpy(&a_vec[0], &g2, sizeof(g2));
    for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(g2); ++i)     
    {         
        cout << hex << static_cast<unsigned>(a_vec[i]) << " ";
    } 
    cout << endl;

    g2 = &C::f2;
    std::vector<unsigned char> a_vec1(sizeof(g2));
    memcpy(&a_vec1[0], &g2, sizeof(g2));

    for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(g2); ++i)     
    {         
        cout << hex << static_cast<unsigned>(a_vec1[i]) << " ";
    } 
    cout << endl;

    cout << sizeof(g) <<endl;
    cout << sizeof(g1) <<endl;
    cout << sizeof(g2) <<endl;

    // Why is sizeof(C) printing 14 and not 20 in visual C++?
    // If yes why is this so ?
    cout << sizeof(C) << endl;
    cout << sizeof(c2) << endl;
    cout << (&c) << endl;
    cout << c.a << endl;
    cout << c.b << endl;
    cout << c.c << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

From the above code sample the Output I get is:

```
inside c::f1
0x1
8
inside c::f2
0x5
18
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
4
8
8
14
14
0xbffe375c
1
2
3
```

Following are my Questions:

1. **Why is the output `1` here in g++ or visual C++?**

   > cout << g2;
2. **Why is the `sizeof` returning `8`? Please explain.**

   > cout << sizeof(g2) << endl;
3. **Why is `sizeof(C)` printing `14` and not `20` in visual C++? If yes why is this so?**

   > cout << sizeof(C) << endl;

Comment: Please note that sizeof(C) is printing 20 if the memcpy code is commented and 14 if it is not commented?.. Please explain

Comment: And at least provide a question...

Comment: Please edit your question so that it has some text, explaining what the problem is, what the output is, etc. Parsing that long block of code to read the comments is just not nice at all.

Comment: For those interested: There are actually 3 questions hidden in the source.

Comment: Sorry.. I have edited the post..

Comment: And please format the code so it's slightly readable - indentation is a must, at least.

Answer (score 3):

**Why is the `sizeof` returning `8`. Please explain?**

```
cout <<sizeof(g2)<<endl;
```

returns 8 because `g2` is a pointer and size of an pointer on your enviornment is 8.

---

**Why is the output `1` here in g++ or visual C++?**

```
cout << g2;
```

The `<< operator` does not have an overloaded version which accepts a pointer. So the pointer gets converted to a bool type, with a value 1, and `cout` prints it.

The C++ Standard allows this:

**C++03 Standard 4.12 Boolean conversions**

> 1 An rvalue of arithmetic, enumeration, pointer, or pointer to member type can be converted to an rvalue of type bool.

---

**Why is `sizeof(C)` printing `14` and not `20` in visual C++.**

```
cout<<sizeof(C)<<endl;
```

It displays the size of `C` correctly just in hexadecimal(`14 in hex` == `20 in decimal`). This is because you used the `hex` I/O manippulator to print an address before.

```
cout<<dec<<sizeof(C)<<endl;
```

will set the I/O manipulator to decimal mode again and it will output `20` as you expect.

---

**A word about `printf` and type safety:**

`printf` is not type safe.When using `printf` it is the users responsibility to pass the proper formart descriptor and data type to it. If there is a mismatch then an **Undefined Behavior** will occur. An Undefined behavior means that the program might crash or show any weird behavior.

> printf( "%p\n", g2 );

Is an example of Undefined Behavior, there is a mismatch in the format descriptor and the data type. Note that the compiler does complain about this and you should always look out and check such warnings emitted by the compiler.

> warning: format ‘%p’ expects type ‘void*’, but argument 2 has type ‘void (C::*)()’

Comment: @RishiMehta because function pointers are not regular pointers. In your platform, they happen to be 4 bytes big.

Comment: @Als Well spotted with the boolean conversion.  I'd missed that.

Answer (score 0):

The results of `sizeof` for a given type never change.  (At least for a
conforming C++ program.  g++, I believe, supports VLAs in C++, as an
extension, and the `sizeof` an object containing a VLA might change.)
With regards to your explicit questions:

```
printf( "%p\n", g2 );
```

is undefined behavior.  You're passing a pointer to member to an output
formatter which requires a `void*`.  (g++ will warn about this, I
believe, at least with certain options.)  You might get just about
anything (including a program crash).  Pointers to members are **not**
`void*`, and can't be converted to `void*`.

```
cout << g2;
```

I can't believe that this compiles.

```
cout << sizeof(g2) << endl;
```

`sizeof(g2)` returns 8 because this is the size of a pointer to member
on your system.

```
cout << sizeof(C) << endl;
```

Prints 14 because this is the size in hexadecimal of an object of type
`C` on your system.  In other words, `sizeof(C)` is 20.  Since you've
set output for `hex`, and never reset it, the output is hexadecimal.